# Limit to number of overviews in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am creating a general map that has seven (7) detailed map frames in QGIS 2.18.10. I want to show the overviews of all these frames on my general map. Unfortunately, not all map frames show in the combo box.

[image: Print Composer showing only 4 overviews]

[image: Map frame combo not showing all the map frames]

Is there a limit to the number of overviews you could show?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there there is no limited number of overview maps created in QGIS. I used QGIS 2.14.15 LTR (Old LTR) and until now I could create 7 overview maps as you can see below:

[image]

One possible issue, you need to fix the scale of the large frame (the one that shows all the overviews). If you didn't fix the scale, it may not show the overview positions of other the frames correctly.

Comment: Thanks! :) I tried moving the sub maps to a second page and checked the map frame combo. All map frames are shown. Problem now is how i will place the sub maps so it will show in the overviews the way I want to place them.